# Algolia error when trying to reindex()

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I'm using the PHP version of AlgoliaSearch with a laravel 5.2 installation.

I created a command I can run to reindex the data I have for one model. It works perfectly on some other but it seems that one has a problem.

When I try to run

```
\App\Models\User::reindex();
```

I get this exception :

```
AlgoliaSearch\AlgoliaException: cannot move with a master/slave index as source
```

I guess there is a problem with the way I configured my index and its slaves but I have no clue on that.

Does someone has more info please ?

Comment: Can you share `$algoliaSettings` variable of your model?

Comment: Of course, [here they are](http://pastebin.com/aDtfkKpj)

Comment: @JanPetr do you need anything else ?